# AWS S3 Copy/Move Specific set of files from lists to S3 buckets in single command line (Creating dynamic inclusion & exclusion)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have around 50K files in my local file system from which I want to move/copy specific files from FILELIST using aws copy/move command line and move all them in one short

Problem here is, I am not able to use `--exclude "*" --include File300 --include File1 --include File5000` so on.

This include list is completely dynamic, it depends on what file names that I have in the FILELIST and number of files in it.

I can do this in a for loop like `` for f in `cat FILELIST` ``  and copy one by one but is there any way to dynamically create `--include` statements and pass them as a parameter to achieve file copy at one shot?

**Example:**

Created a variable `awsvar` and dynamically assigned files inclusion list to get it processed in one shot

```
awsvar='--include "GTRDW_Download_Status-FX-US-C2-598610498-03-01-2023.01_47-en-5240.zip" 
--include "GTRDW_Download_Status-IG-US-C2-597149229-02-28-2023.22_47-en-6120.zip" 
--include "GTRDW_Download_Status-CL-US-C2-595132260-02-28-2023.17_47-en-0003.zip" 
--include "GTRDW_Download_Status-CD-US-C2-592553594-02-28-2023.05_07-en-3451.zip" 
--include "GTRDW_Download_Status-FX-US-C2-596226872-02-28-2023.20_47-en-5190.zip"'
```

Executing S3 Copy dynamically:

```
aws s3 cp /apps/resources/sdr/reports/batch_download/output/ s3://dwr-qap-snowflake-us-east-1/NOA_Outbound_Json/ --recursive --exclude "*" $awsvar
```

Above statement not throwing any errors, it doing a scan but is not copying files to S3.

I tried multiple options in the above command line like:

1. Adding quotes `"$awsvar"`  (Throwing an error "Unknown options: --include")
2. Adding `--include "$awsvar"`  (skipping first include from variable and added to command line)

Nothing worked out.

Comment: After my multiple attempt of retry, I figured out the answers
multiple files uploads works fine with below changes

BDR_LIST=" --include GTRDW_Download_Status-FX-US-C2-598610498-03-01-2023.01_47-en-5240.zip --include GTRDW_Download_Status-IG-US-C2-597149229-02-28-2023.22_47-en-6120.zip"


Single Command line
aws s3 ${AWS_S3_ENDPOINT} cp /apps/resources/sdr/reports/batch_download/output/ s3://dwr-qap-snowflake-us-east-1/NOA_Outbound_Json/ --recursive --exclude "*" ${BDR_LIST} --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id $S3KMS

Comment: Glad to know you got it working! If you think your answer will help future readers, then please **add an Answer to your question**. Or, if you don't think this will help anyone (due to something specific in your environment), you are welcome to Delete your Question.

Comment: By mistake I hit the comment button, I was intend to post my answers.  Thanks @JohnRotenstein  for pointing this else I  could have left unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question:

1. Yes, we can able to copy multiple files to S3 bucker using AWS CLI S3 Copy with single command line without looping
2. For that define a variable as like below and append all your file name in it. (key : don't enclose each file name in "")

```
BDR_LIST=" --include GTRDW_Download_Status-FX-US-C2-598610498-03-01-2023.01_47-en-5240.zip --include GTRDW_Download_Status-IG-US-C2-597149229-02-28-2023.22_47-en-6120.zip"
```

3. Use a usual S3 copy statement in which use the above defined parameter

```
aws s3 cp /apps/resources/sdr/reports/batch_download/output/ s3://dwr-qap-snowflake-us-east-1/NOA_Outbound_Json/ --recursive --exclude "*" ${BDR_LIST} --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id $S3KMS
```

4. This will copy all selective files from your list to copy S3 buckets in one command line

**Note:** Ensure your S3 temporary key get refreshed in parallel just in case if you copying more files because S3 session keys may get expired in the middle of copy execution.